# Only certain devices allowed to use enterprise app

Tags: ios, xcode

could I potentially require UDIDs for internal distribution as well?

Currently, I sign the .deb file and install the resulting .ipa file on every single iOS device myself. I only have a normal developer's license, and now I am thinking to get the enterprise license in order to speed up the process of installing the in house app. It's important though that I am able to limit the devices that use it to prevent it from leaking.

Last but not least, with the normal developer's license the app stops working after 365 days and it needs to be resigned and reinstalled. Is this the same behavior with the enterprise license and the in home distribution?

Comment: Did you have a specific programming question? Maybe try asking this on the dev forums?

Comment: True, that might be a better place to ask for since it's not necessarily a programming question. Which forum do you think would fit best?